# React Dropzone does not work correctly with .pkl files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dropzone

I try to use React Dropzone for .pkl and .pk files.

```
<DropzoneDialog
   acceptedFiles=[".pkl, .pk"]
/>
```

But when I drag the .pkl file, DropZone becomes red and then accepts file. Does anybody know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

maybe like this :

for image its like this --- updated ---

```
<DropzoneDialog
  acceptedFiles={['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/bmp']}
/>
```

check something like :

```
<DropzoneDialog
  acceptedFiles={['application/python-pickle']}
/>
```

--- update ---

[NO SOLUTION](https://github.com/react-dropzone/react-dropzone/tree/master/examples/accept#browser-limitations)

Comment: i dont have pkl file, can you share one ?

Comment: Try this:  application/octet-stream

Comment: I tried. No result. File is no event accepted with this option

Comment: https://github.com/react-dropzone/react-dropzone/tree/master/examples/accept#browser-limitations